# retrieve data using jquery ajax from php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I trying to retrieve data from database using sql code in php 
I successfully retrieve the data by using this method

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    'use strict';
  $('#JSONoffers').load('getOffers.php?useJSON')});
```

However, i requested to retrieve the data using `$.ajax()`method.
So here comes the problem.
Here is the partial code of my php.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['useJSON'])) {
    // echo what getJSONOFfer returns
    echo getJSONOffer($conn);
}
function getJSONOffer($conn) {
    $sql = "select eventTitle, catDesc, eventPrice from te_events_special_offers inner join te_category on te_events_special_offers.catID = te_category.catID order by rand() limit 1";
    $rsOffer = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    //$offer = mysqli_fetch_all($rsOffer, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $offer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsOffer);
    return json_encode($offer);
}
```

First, i would like to inform that most of the example or asked question found from the internet that similar to this question but least, they have JSON file or other value that i do not have in my php.
I tried to use below code as my reference, but, it retrieve using json file which having `title`, `author` to called.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   'use strict';
   $('#getBooks').click(function () {
       $.ajax({
           dataType: "json",
           method: "get",
           url: "server/books.json"}
       )
       .done(function (data, status, jqxhr) {
               var bookList = $('#bookList').append('<dl/>');
               window.console && console.log(status + '\n'+data.books);
               $(data.books).each(function () {
                    $(bookList).find('dl').append("<dt><h3>"+this.title+
                                                  "</h3></dt><dd><p>"+this.author+
                                                  "</p><p>"+this.description+"</p></dd>");
               });
           }
       )
       .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                window.console && console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
           }
       );
       $(this).attr("disabled", true);
   });
});
```

In fact, there are only sql code in my php.
Also, i tried the following method but it doesn't work, and there is no any error on the console (which is quite hard for me to find the error/mistake).

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    'use strict';

  //change the onclick to .load
     $('#JSONoffers').load(function () {

       $.ajax({
           dataType: "json",
           method: "get",
           url: "getOffers.php?useJSON"}
       )}
     });
})
```

Someone pls help me with this.Much Appreciate!


And now, i tried the following code by referring to other sources and still doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    'use strict';

   //$('#JSONoffers').load('getOffers.php?useJSON')
     $('#JSONoffers').load(function () {

       $.ajax({
           dataType: "json",
           url: "getOffers.php?useJSON",
           success : function(data){
            $('#JSONoffers').html(data);
        }   
       })
     })
})
```

Comment: you're not even processing the response? how can you say it's not working? you don't even have a callback function in your ajax call

Comment: sir can u provide me some link or example?

Answer (score 0):

You'r doing it wrong I think. `.load` is like from my understand an `ajax` call as well, it request the content and send it to the client and display. However, ajax is more deep than that since from ajax you can manipulate the Request headers and the response as well. So doing both is not really ideal. If you want to load your content or display your content from the response. Do like below:

```
 $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    method: "get",
    url: "getOffers.php?useJSON"
 }).done(function(res){
    //do anything with the response here
 });
```

Comment: Yes, from a certain verison, `.load()` became somewhat of a `ajax` call aswell. If you want to wait for the load, you'll have to use the `.on("load",function(){})` functionality.

Comment: @Nytrix got your point, he's trying to actually replace `.load` with `ajax` however, he's having a hard time on understand both And he is trying to actually load a content not listen to the `load` event.